# WinForms, .NET - reading settings file in compiled program

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, security, passwords

I was wondering how easy it is to read information from settings file once the application is compiled to binary?
I mean, extracting the data of settings **using third party applications**, like Notepad or something else.

I just want to make login form autofill if user pressed 'Remember Me' and place the credentials encrypted somewhere in Temp folder. To be able to track the file once application is loaded, I want to save the path to user's settings file and read it after the app is launched.

Comment: Everything on the users computer belongs to him and can be read by him. But the user entered the credentials in the first place, so there there should be no reason to try to hide them.

Comment: There should... At least in my opinion. Think of someone breaching into your computer and having the ability to easily read all your stored passwords. Not good.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I had the same problem.
To save your data do:

```
string[] accountData = { nick, password };
if(checkbox.Checked)
{
     System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"YourFile.txt", data);
}
```

To autofill it in text boxes do:

```
string[] accountData = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"YourFile.txt");
TextBox1 = accountData[0];
TextBox2 = accountData[1];
```

I'm glad that will help you.

EDIT: I assume that when you are loggining in you are just entering `nick`into `TextBox1` and `password` into `TextBox2` you can use more data if you want just use `string[] accountData = { variable1, variable2, variable3, etc... }`and in read just use `accountData[1], accountData[2], accountData[3], etc...`

If you want you can use anything else instead `txt`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though it is not what I am asking. I want to be sure, if writing temp file path to settings is a safe practice. I know how to do all the auto-filling thing and encryption of data. By the way, there's some serious security issue with your approach - you are saving login credentials as plain text, so any intruder can just take it as a present.

Answer (score 0):

Use projects properties to create the new setting and store/update the value of setting. Below is the screen shot:

[image]

You can use `Properties.Settings.Default.YourSettingName` to access your setting. And Properties.Settings.Default.Save() function to save the setting. Below is the code snippet:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.YourSettingName = "NewSettingValue";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

After compilation of application, setting is available in the bin\release directory and its name is YourApplicationName.exe.config. You can open it in notepad and change the value of your setting and exe will start using this updated value without recompiling. However you have to restart the exe to get the updated value from the .exe.config file if it is running.

Also it is not advisable to store sensitive information in settings. Hope it will serve the purpose.

Comment: Please read second sentence of my question once again. I am not asking how to save or read settings in code.

Comment: On load event of your login form, read the path from the settings as suggested by me. Then read the credentials from this path and fill it in text box. Place a remember me check box on login form. On click event of Login button, encrypt the password and save it to the path that you read from the settings. Do it to store the updated password after every successful login attempt but if remember me is checked.

Comment: That's what I wanted to do. And I knew the solution from the very start. But the essence of my question is how easily that path could be read by third parties... I mean, is it safe to store stuff in Settings or those Settings can be read by human easily after the program is compiled. Like, is the settings file compiled into some kind of binary or just a seperate file that you can open with notepad and read easily.

Comment: After compilation of application it is available in the bin\release directory and its name is YourApplicationName.exe.config. You can open it in notepad and change the value of your setting and exe will start using this updated value without recompiling. However you have to restart the exe to get the updated value from the .exe.config file if it is running.

Comment: That means it is not safe to store path to my encrypted password there... THAT's what I wanted to know. Thank you!

Comment: Edit your answer so it matches your comment and I'll accept it!

Comment: Edited answer as per your request.

Comment: The top part of your answer is still irrelevant to the question. Remove everything before 'After compilation of aplication...'